# MEAN: Getting total value from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

Im new to mean stack and Im using mongoskin to connect to mongodb..Im trying to get total value present in database

```
function getTotal() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var dashboard = db.collection('dashboard');

    db.collection('dashboard').find({"iscorrect" : ""}).count(),
    function (err, doc) {
        if (err){
            deferred.reject(err);
        } else{
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    };

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

my main controller has

```
function gettotal(req, res) {
    userService.getTotal()
        .then(function () {
            res.sendStatus(200);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            res.status(400).send(err);
        });
}
```

The following code does not return any value...Any help in getting total value is helpful
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because **[`count()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#count)** method is asynchronous and returns a promise, you can restructure your function as either using a callback function

```
function getTotal() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();        
    db.collection('dashboard').count({"iscorrect" : ""}, function (err, result) {
        if (err){
            deferred.reject(err);
        } else{
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

or since **[`count()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#count)** returns a Promise, just return it

```
function getTotal() {
    // just return a Promise
    return db.collection('dashboard').count({"iscorrect" : ""});        
}
```

and in your controller:

```
function gettotal(req, res) {
    userService.getTotal()
        .then(function (count) {
            res.status(200).json({ 'count': count });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            res.status(400).send(err);
        });
}
```